# To add space to a VARCHAR column value to ensure a minimum length of 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table TEST_TABLE having a column with name as LNAME having VARCHAR2 data type.
The requirement is that the value of LNAME must be minimum of 2 characters.

1- Create table

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
(
  LNAME VARCHAR2(4000)
);
```

2 - insert record with length 1

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (LNAME) VALUES ('A');
```

LNAME is having value `'A'`.
I need to transform this value to `'A '`. [With an added space to ensure minimum length condition is satisfied].

Note: need to be done using CASE...WHEN

My attempt:

```
select
CASE
WHEN LENGTH(LNAME) < 2
THEN RPAD(LNAME,2)
ELSE ''
END LNAME
from TEST_TABLE;
```

Using the below query to check the length:

```
select LENGTH(LNAME) from TEST_TABLE;
```

The length returns as 1 and not 2 as expected. 
Is RPAD the right way to append the space to the end of "A"?

Comment: Are you trying to cheat?!? "_The requirement is that the value of LNAME must be minimum of 2 characters._"

Comment: Why do you want to specifically add space. You should not manipulate the data

Comment: @VenkataramanR Manipulation of data is what is needed for me to further use my data ahead for further operations.

Comment: @jarlh No Sir, I am unfortunately not trying to cheat. Pardon my poor choice of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rpad()` should work, but your `else` might be causing problems:

```
select (case when length(lname) < 2 then rpad(lname, 2)
             else lname
        end) as lname
from TEST_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CHECK` constraint on the column:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
(
  LNAME VARCHAR2(4000) CONSTRAINT TEST_TABLE__LNAME__MINLENGTH2 CHECK ( LENGTH( LNAME ) >= 2 )
);
```

Then you can use your `RPAD` in your insert statement if the value is too short:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE ( LNAME ) VALUES ( RPAD( 'A', 2 ) );
```

or you could use a `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO TEST_TABLE t
USING ( SELECT 'A' AS value FROM DUAL ) v
ON ( 0 = 1 )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( LNAME ) VALUES ( CASE WHEN LENGTH( v.value ) < 2 THEN RPAD( v.value, 2 ) ELSE v.value END );
```

Or an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
  value TEST_TABLE.LNAME%TYPE := 'B';
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test_table ( lname ) VALUES ( CASE WHEN LENGTH( value ) < 2 THEN RPAD( value, 2 ) ELSE value END );
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2fe0997e59ce749cb08603bf2f5aab97)*

If you want to change your existing data then use an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET    lname = RPAD( lname, 2 )
WHERE  LENGTH( lname ) < 2
```